# TinyMCE Preview Not Working in IE 8 and IE 7

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Im working with a web app and i used the latest version of tinyMCE as editor on the backend..
everything looks fine except with the template preview on IE..

is there anyone who encounter or has a fix for this??

THanks in advance.

here is my code

```
   tinyMCE.init({
// General options
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

// Theme options
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,

// Skin options
skin : "o2k7",
skin_variant : "silver",

// Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
template_external_list_url : "../../js/tiny_mce/plugins/template/template_list_2.php",
external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

editor_selector : "htmlEditor",
convert_urls : false,
width : "100%",
height: "500px",

init_instance_callback : function() { 
    $('.mceToolbar a').each(function(item){
        $(this).attr('tabindex', -1);
    }); 
}
```

});

Comment: You mean frontend? I bet the answer provided here http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26000 is the best answer for the question.

Comment: @vision thanks for your reply.. but the forum you have suggested doesn't makes sense for me.. Thanks

i think it will took me more time to research

Comment: I mean that there is not enough information to fix the problem. By all my search, there shouldn't be any problems with preview in IE.

Answer (score 0):

add youre code to here.
if the code work fine in FF&chrome i guess you may left Trailing Comma